# Connecting to PostgreSQL through WSL in PhpStorm

Tags: php, postgresql, phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Running PhpStorm on Windows 10. PostgreSQL is on my WSL instance of Ubuntu 20.04.

Trying to connect to the IP that is found by using `wsl hostname -I` using the built in Database interface/browser in PhpStorm.

[image: Image Settings in PhpStorm]

Is there a different port or setting I am suppose to use? Thank you!

Comment: You tried this and it's not working? Did you get an error somewhere?

Comment: Yeah,[08001] Connection to 172.29.94.105:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
Connection to 172.29.94.105:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Comment: Did you enabled remote access to PostgreSQL server?

Comment: Try connecting to `localhost:5432` instead

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this answer isn't too late.

My DB is running inside a Docker container that runs inside the WSL machine. So, in order to connect to the DB, I had to log in to my WSL instance and run the `ip addr` command there. The output will be similar to this:

```
## NOTE THAT I REMOVED SOME UNRELEVANT LINES IN ORDER TO SIMPLIFY MY ANSWER

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:15:5d:e9:56:df brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.21.130.250/20 brd 172.21.143.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fee9:56df/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
link/ether 02:42:fc:eb:bc:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

WSL IP is `172.21.130.250`, so I filled PhpStorm with the IP corresponding to that WSL instance (`172.21.130.250`) and MySQL port (`18766` - since my DB is running within Docker, the port is different of default 3306 and can be found in your Docker configuration). It worked fine.